# When should I set localStorage in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, routes, local-storage

I have a list of employee list on `EmployeesComponent` and there is "Education Overview" and "Salary Overview" buttons for each records. When I click one of the overview button it goes to the `OverviewComponent` first and then load the correponding component (salary or education) into this `OverviewComponent`. There is also a "Back" button on each of these salary and education components. The structure is as shown on the following image:

[components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkU2p.png)

The problem is that: When I come back to the `EmployeesComponent`, I need to reload the paging params e.g. the last page number before navigating to the overview pages. For this I use `localStorage` and check the saved value on each page load of the `EmployeesComponent`.

```
searchParams: any;

ngOnInit() {
  let searchParams = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('routeParams'))?.searchParameters;
  if(searchParams){
    this.searchParams = searchParams;
    window.localStorage.removeItem('routeParams'); // remove routeParams from localStorage
  
  // load list using this.searchParams
}
```

But I save the page params on the `OverviewComponent` so that use a single place for salary and education pages. I think it is not a good approach and it may cause the localStorage items to be mixed as they use the same key (for some reason I need to use the same key sometimes).

So, should I set the paging parameters just before navigating to the overview page in the `EmployeesComponent`? And then check them on loading `EmployeesComponent`? What is a proper way for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query-params in routing.
So now when you redirect from `employess component` to `overViewComponent`, then based on click i.e., **Education Overview** or **Salary Overview** just send the query params with the url.

Then now when you get back to `employess component`, just use the query params value you get in `overView component` and you can get the information you want back in `employess component`.

Q- what is the most proper place for adding and removing paging items to local storage

A- Most proper place for adding and removing localstorage item is where it get's change.
In your case, just set localstorage in overView component where you are getting params ( this.activateRoute.params() ) inside this function. And remove the localstorage on ngOnInit function of employee component.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I use `queryParams`, but when refreshing the overview pages, these params are gone. For this reason I should use `localStorage` I think. Currently I use `queryParams` just for passing the parameters to the Overview component, but then I save these parameters to `localStorage`.

Comment: Then if your app is refreshing, then storing data in localstorage is  best way. @Lily

Comment: Ok, but I already use it. My question is **what is the most proper place** for adding and removing paging items to local storage? Could you please have a look at the scenario again explained above? Regards.

Comment: Updated. Please check the answer again. @Lily

Comment: Thanks for update. What about both setting and getting `localstorage` on `EmployeeComponent`?

Comment: That approach is also completely ok. Go ahead you are on right path. @Lily